# List<Color> in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my List defined in Xaml like this.

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:FileName x:Key="fileName">
        <Color>#3599B8</Color>
        <Color>#374649</Color>
        <Color>#FD625E</Color>
        <Color>#F2C80F</Color>
      </local:FileName> 
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

FileName is defined in code behind like this.

```
public class FileName : List<Color>
    {

    }
```

Instead of directly setting the Color values, i want to define it as resource like this

```
<Color x:Key="BasicColorSchemeBlue">#3599B8</Color>
```

and use it.

Any suggestions on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of the question, I'm curious to know why would a class named `FileName` inherits from a List of colors...

Comment: @JoshPart That was just for testing purpose. I have property with type List<Color> and I am setting its value from ResourceDictionary.

Comment: The question isn't very clear either. Either way, `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource` will only search for keys in the top level of your `ResourceDictionary`. So you can't set keys on the children of the `fileName` resource.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 2):

> GradientColors is an array of Colors.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GradientTest"
                 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                 x:Class="GradientTest.GradientTestPage">
        <StackLayout Padding="20, 40, 20, 20">
            <local:GradientViewRender HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                      WidthRequest="300" 
                                      HeightRequest="50" 
                                      x:Name="gradientView">

                <local:GradientViewRender.GradientColors>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type Color}"> 
                        <Color>#5FC900</Color>
                        <Color>#0FF2C8</Color> 
                    </x:Array>
                </local:GradientViewRender.GradientColors>
            </local:GradientViewRender>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this on a working App.
This goes inside App.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="COLOR_NAME">#ffffff</Color>
```

to access the color from a .cs file, use:

```
(Color)ResourceFinder.FindResource("COLOR_NAME");
```

Or use StaticResource or DynamicResource within an xaml file.