# Declare array of array in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to use an inline data source for a data grid, and obviously XAML supports array of builtin types with [x:Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-array-markup-extension), but when I tried to declare a nested array, tried a few ways but none of them works.

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type Array}">
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
        <x:String>aaa1</x:String>
        <x:String>aaa2</x:String>
    </x:Array>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
        <x:String>aaa9</x:String>
        <x:String>aaa10</x:String>
    </x:Array>
</x:Array>
```

This wont work either:

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type {x:Array Type={x:Type String}}">
```

Comment: " A Type parameter value does not need to use an x:Type markup extension;"  
Have you tried to write `Type="{x:Array}"`?

Comment: @Rebecca yes I tried it, it compiles ok but nothing shows in the listview

Comment: Its work for me in Xamarin.Forms application.
[Xamarin.Forms xaml colors array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243530/8490598).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<x:Array xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Key="array" Type="{x:Type s:Array}">
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type s:String}">
        <s:String>aaa1</s:String>
        <s:String>aaa2</s:String>
    </x:Array>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type s:String}">
        <s:String>aaa9</s:String>
        <s:String>aaa10</s:String>
    </x:Array>
</x:Array>
```

Sample usage:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource array}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This wont compile :(

Comment: It surely does  - in WPF. Which is the tag you have marked your question with.

Comment: Ok, vs just failes with value cannot be null, I will try again.

Comment: Copy the array above into <Window.Resources>. It works for me.